# Can a healed fracture impact the structure of the sinus?

Tags: bacteria, bone-fractures, sinus

Could a healed fracture, years old, cause ridges/distress in the sinus? Enough for bacteria or fungus to cling to and cause a sinus infection?

I researched some pictures of how the inside of the sinus looks and it seems to be mostly soft tissue. To me this makes it look like a healed fracture, even if it wasn't healed that neatly, couldn't cause any rigs or bumps that bacteria could house in easily, because the tissue would have grown over it by now.

So my question is: **Can a healed fracture impact the structure of the inside of the sinus?** Or will the soft tissue do it's job?